# Biggest value of the value of a function in a given triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help understanding a particular problem.
Let's say we're given the triangle given by the lines
$x=-1$, $y=-1$, and $y=1-x$ and the function $f(x,y) = x^3+6xy+6y^2$.
I already found all critical points inside the triangle ($M(0,0)$ and $P(1,-1/2)$) and found the smallest and biggest values of the sides of the triangle (of course in my given range)

However, what I cannot seem to understand is why do I have to check the value of the POINTS of the triangle (where the given lines intersect) for biggest and smallest value as well. I thought when we were checking for the whole line, let's say $x=-1$, with range $[-1,2]$ we already included them( points of intersection $A(-1,2)$ and $B(-1,-1)$ are already included?). Why do I have to check for them separetely?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:
In finding the maximum of $f(X)=x^2$ over $[-1,2]$ if we look for critical values of $f$ on the whole line we will miss the maximizer $x=2$. This point becomes a maimum due to the restriction on the domain.

Same happens with the triangle. A corner may not be a maximizer along either of the lines of intersection -- the function would attain bigger values if we move outside the tringle in either of those directions. However, because we cut the region there, that vertex becomes a maximum.

Comment: Ahhh I get it. So when I check for the whole line, there may be a bigger value of f, for e.g in the point M(-1, 1000), and as such the point in my range will be missed, since f(M) it is not bigger than lets say f(-1, 2). However, P(-1,2) will stil be a local extremum, since only it and not M, is included in the range.

Thank you!